# Load file.q from path containing space character

Tags: kdb, q-lang

How to load script file from a path containing spaces?

For example, this works:

```
\l F:/file.q
```

Below attempts throw an error:

```
\l  F:/Folder with spaces/file.q
\l "F:/Folder with spaces/file.q"
\l hsym `$"F:/Folder with spaces/file.q"
system "l "F:/Folder with spaces/file.q""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly practical, but if you need to load files with spaces in the path, you can use windows short file names:

So given a script path: `F://Folder with spaces/file with spaces.q`

Given

- `Folder with spaces` gets shortname `folder~1`
- `script with spaces.q` gets shortname `filewi~.q`

You can load the file as follows in q:

```
q)system "l F://folder~1/filewi~1.q"
    Hello from a q script with spaces in file name
```

You can get the short name of a file/folder by listing the directory in command print with `/x` flag (eg. `dir /x`)

---

As in general with this situation in windows, you're likely better off avoiding spaces in a filepath.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post, but just had the same issue. Found a solution that works for me:

```
system "cd c:/your path/with spaces/"
system "l your_script.q"
```